# MVVMCross Behaviours and InvokeCommandAction

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm relatively new to MVVMCross and MVVM architecture.

I'm trying to keep my CodeBehind as clean as possible so I've been using `Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors` to trigger a command when clicking on an Item:

```
<views:MvxStorePage.Resources>
        <core:Theme x:Key="Theme"/>
        <b:NameScopeBinding  x:Key="ModuleGridView" Source="{Binding ElementName=ModuleGridView}" />
</views:MvxStorePage.Resources>
...
<GridView x:Name="ModuleGridView" >
...
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
          <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectModuleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source.SelectedItem, Source={StaticResource ModuleGridView}}" />
     </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
...
</GridView>
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
MvxCommand<object> _selectModuleCommand;
        public ICommand SelectModuleCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _selectModuleCommand = _selectModuleCommand ?? new MvxCommand<object>((obj) => SelectModule(obj));
                return _selectModuleCommand;
            }
        }

        private void SelectModule(object module)
        {
            var test = 1;
        }
```

Problem is that the object passed in to `SelectModule` is of type `ItemClickedEventArgs` which isn't available in the PCL core project where my ViewModels are located. So i can't access the `ItemClicked` property of that object.

I've tried using this from my ´InvokeCommandAction´

```
 <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectModuleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source.SelectedItem.ClickedItem, Source={StaticResource ModuleGridView}}" />
```

But it has no effect, i still get `ItemClickedEventArgs` as parameter to my Command

Comment: You can try writing your own interactions which will be more portable - here's some from WindowsPhone - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Commands (comment only for now - will try to return with full answer eventually!)

Comment: You could try using `dynamic`, I believe.

Comment: @NateDiamond The dynamic property would be different on each platform?

Comment: @Stuart Sorry for being unclear but those sources are for Windows Phone. I'm trying to solve this on a store project.

Comment: `dynamic` loads the properties and methods for an object at runtime (basically using a Dictionary, similar to how Python or Javascript works). This has some pretty serious performance implications, but can allow you to treat an object in a particular way (such as calling a given method or property) and so long as it has that method or property, it won't have a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved using the property `InputConverter` of InvokeCommandAction.

```xml
<Page.Resource>
    <local:ItemClickedConverter x:Key="ItemClickedConverter" />
</Page.Resource>

<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <icore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
        <icore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectModuleCommand}"
                                   InputConverter="{StaticResource ItemClickedConverter}" />
    </icore:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And here is the implementation for `ItemClickedConverter`:

```cs
public class ItemClickedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value switch {
            null => null,
            ItemClickEventArgs args => args.ClickedItem,
            _ => throw new ArgumentException(),
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```